# Data Frame from an existing RDD - Python Spark

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am trying to create a Data Frame from an existing RDD by specifying the column label and data type, but I get this Typeerror:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *

sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
yFieldTypes = [FloatType()]
ySchemaString = "Predictor"
fy_data = [StructField(field_name, field_type, True) \
          for field_name, field_type in zip(ySchemaString.split(), yFieldTypes)]
schema_y = StructType(fy_data)
```

So the schema is as follows:

```
StructType(List(StructField(Predictor,FloatType,true)))
```

And my RDD datay.take(10) output is as follows:

```
 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

When I want to create my data frame:

```py
dfy = sqlContext.createDataFrame(datay, schema_y)
```

I get this Typeerror:

```
TypeError: StructType(List(StructField(Predictor,FloatType,true))) can not accept object in type <type 'float'>
```

Comment: have you tried calling toDF() on your rdd?

Answer (score 0):

That's because it is not correct schema. Since you have atomic types, you should use `FloatType` directly:

```
dfy = sqlContext.createDataFrame(datay, FloatType())
```

and to use current schema you should use tuples:

```
dfy = sqlContext.createDataFrame(datay.map(lambda x: (x, )), schema_y)
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue is because `RDD` is of `Double` type and `schema` is defined as `FloatType`. You will have to find a way to **convert Double rdds to Float**.

I haven't worked with `pyspark` but I am going to post below `scala` code to help you.

```
val datay = sc.parallelize(Seq(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0))

val r = datay.map(d => Row.fromSeq(Seq(d.toFloat)))

val schema_y = StructType(List(StructField("Predictor", FloatType, true)))

val dfy = sqlContext.createDataFrame(r, schema_y)
```

I hope this will help you reach to the solution you require